# Get Amount From Coinbase Payment Button

Tags: javascript, dom-events, payment, bitcoin, coinbase-api

I am trying to implement coinbase payment on my website.

I'm using the embed payment button here: https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/#payment-buttons

I am using the Javascript `BuyWithCrypto` class to register a callback which calls a script that processes the customer's request after the function is called. The called PHP script is supposed to update a database table with the amount deposited by the customer.

```
BuyWithCrypto.registerCallback('onSuccess', function(e){
    // Charge was successfully completed
    window.location.assign("process.php")

});
```

Everything works fine but I am having issues detecting how much the user deposited to the generated address.

I Just want to know if it is possible to get the amount the user deposited when the `onSuccess` function is called.

Comment: Get it from the amount field...  Can you show us the HTML with the amount and button?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var amt=document.getElementById("amt");
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", purchase);

function purchase() { // put this in first line of callback
  var amtPaid=parseFloat(
    amt.options[amt.selectedIndex].innerText
  );
 console.log(amtPaid);
  // do what you want with amtPaid
}
```

```html
Amount:
<select id="amt">
  <option> 9.99</option>
  <option>19.99</option>
  <option>29.99</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">Pay</button>
```